# What is the MVVM way to create UI elements at run time?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am developing an application that will require UserControls to be created based on user interaction. The number of controls can vary based on what the user has selected. Lets say I have a parent container user control called "View" and my ViewModel which we will call "ViewModel". In my ViewModel class I have a List and I want to create a UserControl for each ObjectViewModel in the list. What design patterns are recommended for this?

Comment: Use DataTemplates that contain your UserControls. A DataTemplate is associated with a view model class by its DataType property. See [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview).

Comment: ItemsControl (with custom ItemTempate) is your friend.

Comment: https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/28/switching-between-viewsusercontrols-using-mvvm/

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. One follow up though. Each of the user controls is associated with a view model. How do I set the data context for a control added using Data Template?

Comment: @AndrewMurphy, the datacontext for an itemtemplate is automatically set, according to the viewmodels in the ItemsSource.